Proving That Sums and Products Of Finite-Valued Measurable Functions Are Measurable
I'm currently going through Real Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi. On page 29 of the book, Stein proves that given two measurable and finite valued functions $f$ and $g$, $f+g$ and $fg$ are measurable. This is listed as property 5 (ii).
Stein starts by stating that $f + g$ is measurable, because for any real number $a$, $\{f + g > a\} = \bigcup_{r=Q} \{f > a - r\} \cap \{g > r \}$.
He then shows that $fg$ is measurable based on the fact that $fg$ = $\frac{1}{4} [(f + g)^2 - (f - g)^2]$. Note we have proven the integer power of a measurable function is measurable, as part of property 5 (i).
My question is where does Stein use the assumption that these functions are finite-valued in his proof? If we were to write this proof without the assumption that $f$ and $g$ are finite-valued (or at least finite-valued almost everywhere), where would it fail?

$f+g$ may not even be defined if infinite values are allowed.

@geetha290krm Would that be a problem though? If f and g are both  $\infty$, wouldn't $f + g$ be greater than any natural number $a$? Or does the problem emerge when say f is $\infty$ and g is $-\infty$?

$\infty-\infty$ is not defined.

@geetha290krm Ah yes, that make sense.
